# SqlAlchemy Reflection of Oracle Table Not Owned

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sqlalchemy

I'm working with SQLAlchemy to run SQL queries against an Oracle database. I have read access to the database, but the user I have does not own any of the tables I'm working with.

The database updates on a regular basis, so rather than explicitly listing the MetaData, I was hoping to use reflection. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515610/sqlalchemy-metadata-reflect-not-finding-tables-in-oracle-db), that describes an issue similar to what I'm having. However, I don't have a way to change ownership of the tables, nor modify the database in any way. I just have read access.

Is there a way to reflect Oracle tables in SQLAlchemy if I don't have ownership of those tables?

(Edit)

Example Code:

```
engine = create_engine('ORACLE CONNECTION STRING')

metadata = MetaData()

students = Table('students', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

I receive an exception of `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: students`

However, when I run the following:

```
results = engine.execute('SELECT * FROM students')

for r in results:
    print(r)
```

I receive the output that I expected from the table, which is a tuple of all the fields for each row.

So instead of trying to reflect a single table, I try to reflect all of them:

```
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

print(metadata.tables)
```

The output is `immutabledict({})`.

So essentially it's nothing. All of these tables are owned by user A where as I'm logging in with a read-only of user B.

Comment: If you have read permission on those tables, even if you don't own them, reflection should work just fine.  I regularly work with tables like this.  What specifically is the problem?  SQLA can't help you if you're trying to write to a database you only have read access to.

Comment: I've editted my question with specific code to show what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm new to sqlalchemy, so it is entirely possible I'm not doing something right. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have better luck reflecting someone else's tables if you specify the `schema` (account) you're  targeting:

```
metadata.reflect(bind=engine, schema='userA')
```

This way, you'll reflect all readable tables belonging to 'userA'.  I'm not sure why you're able to query students using `engine.execute`, though.

Comment: That did the trick! Adding schema='userA' to both the total reflect and table specific reflect worked as expected. Thanks again for all your help.